# Node application on server doesnt work, throws express error

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

I'm trying to upload my web application to a server provider, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:668:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:591:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/brechore/teste/dist/server.js:3:39)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
```

On my local pc its working. I uploaded to heroku server and It worked too. I tried to install the express again, with npm, yarn, tried to change the node version, but nothing seems to work.
Does anybody have any ideas? My package.json:

Obs: I tried to contact the server support but they said the problem was in my application.

```json
      {
      "name": "restore",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "server.js",
      "repository": "http://github.com/MrPontas/Restore",
      "author": "MrPontas <guipontarolo@gmail.com>",
      "license": "MIT",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node dist/server.js",
        "build": "babel src --extensions \".js,.ts\" --out-dir dist --copy-files",
        "dev": "ts-node-dev  --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules src/server.ts",
        "typeorm": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.1",
        "typescript": "^4.1.3"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": "11.15"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
        "@babel/node": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.12.1",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
        "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.9",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
        "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata": "^0.3.2",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.5.0",
        "pg": "^8.5.1",
        "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
        "typeorm": "^0.2.30"
      }
    }
```

The server uses cpanel and "Setup nodeJS app", as below:

[image: Setup nodejs app config]

The worktree (I guess is it):

root
--teste
--dist
...
server.js

```
    --node_modules
        ...
        --express
        --express-async-errors

    --public

    tmp
    babel.config.js
    ormconfig.js
    package.json
```

Comment: Just a guess, but it seems like your installation is failing for the packages, which is why it's not finding it. Can you verify that the packages get installed properly on the server?

Comment: Hi Guilherme,
It's a little hard to tell without knowing the file tree and the OS system your server is working on. Would you mind updating your question with that?

Comment: I edited with the information you asked to!